# When did Heroku remove Postgres Connection Pooling from Hobby Tier?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I had a portfolio app that worked great, and I revisited it recently and it seems to have stalled out on all connections to the DB. Looking into it, it seems [Heroku does not allow connection pooling for hobby tier DBs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-connection-pooling). I know this can't have always been the case since it worked when it was initially built, but the documentation doesn't indicate any specific time when this change was made. I'm hoping someone maybe knows when this feature removal was implemented. It seems like useful information that should be included in the documentation since knowing the specific date is helpful in fixing broken applications due to this change.